# Rendering nested components ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my data in this format:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
expenses: {
    byId: {
        k948zpnp: {
            id: 'k948zpnp',
            category: 'other',
            description: 'book',
            amount: '25',
            timeSpent: '2.5',
            time: '2020-04-21'
        }
    },
    allIds: ['k948zpnp']
  }
}
```

What I want to do is render Component that contains date - so all my child components (SingleItem) that have the same time are grouped in it.

```
<ExpensesByDay date={time)>
   <SingleItem restOfData={...} />
</ExpensesByDay>
```

I'm grouping my data by the time property and the final object:

```
   budgetByDay = {
    2020-04-11: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
    2020-04-20: [{…}],
    2020-04-21: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    }
```

Then I make and an array of all the dates and do this:

```
{datesArray.map(date =>
                budgetByday[date].map(item => (
                    <DailyBudget date={date}>
                        <SingleItem
                            keyAndRest={...}
                        />
                    </DailyBudget>
                ))
            )}
```

But this won't work. I'm thinking that my approach might be incorrect from the beginning and I might not need my expenses grouped by date. How would you approach this task?

Comment: What is the exact problem? Are you getting an error or your component is not being rendered as you expect?

Comment: I get no errors, but only the dates are being rendered without expenses inside. Also dates are being repeated instead of Date1: value1, value2. Date2: ...

Comment: Here is the link to example [https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-khayyam-6tdcp?file=/src/App.js]

Comment: It is worth putting your App, DailyBudget and SingeItem components implementation in your initial question, as these details are important to understand your problem.

Comment: @Stepas : I got adjusted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61589735/11299053) to the rest of your environment, you may inquiry that for details along with the link to working codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `budgetByday` is an object, so you can't use `Array.prototype.map()` method directly. Instead, you may extract its entries and map those:

```
<tbody>
        {Object.entries(budgetByday).map(([date, items], key) => [
          <DailyBudget date={date} key={key} />,
          ...items.map(({ id, ...rest }) => <SingleItem key={id} {...rest} />)
        ])}
</tbody>
```

You may check out the updated version of your sandbox [over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sunset-m1gyw?file=/src/App.js:568-797).

Comment: And the last question, is this normal practice to render multiple components this way?

Comment: @Stepas : for multiple different components, which you cannot combine inside common parent node (e.g. dummy-tag `<>`) to keep the rest of mark up consistent, yes, it is legitimate way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `SingleItem` is nested inside `DailyBudget`. That is not correct because in your `DailyBudget` implementation it doesn't render any `children` components. Moreover, you can't place `<tr>` inside another `<tr>` element. So here is corrected code that should work as you expect:

```
    {datesArray.map((date) =>
      <>
        <DailyBudget date={date} key={date} />
        {budgetByday[date].map((dateItem) => <SingleItem {...dateItem} /> )}
      </>
    )}
```